# How to add webkit support to calc?

Tags: css, cross-browser

I can see that calc is more compatible when using webkit. Usually when you add support for webkit or moz you do something like:

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
```

What is the correct syntax for calc?

```
width: -webkit-calc(100% - 100px);
```

Comment: what is the issue you are facing? your syntax is correct. post some codes....

Comment: @AtalKishore Just wanted confirmation as I couldn't find any documentation for this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**correct syntax for calc is**

```
/* Firefox */
width: -moz-calc(100% - 100px);
/* WebKit */
width: -webkit-calc(100% - 100px);
/* Opera */
width: -o-calc(100% - 100px);
/* Standard */
width: calc(100% - 100px)
```

Answer (score 7):

At least you need to support Safari 6, Chrome 25 or FF 15 you just need to write `width: calc(100% - 100px)`

```
// Firefox 4 to 15
width: -moz-calc(100% - 100px);

// Chrome 19 to 25
// Safari 6
width: -webkit-calc(100% - 100px);

// Standard
width: calc(100% - 100px)

// Note: Never existed a Opera prefix for calc
```

Note that never existed the Opera prefix `-o-calc`, since calc was introduced in Opera it always was using just `calc`. You can check the calc support in [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc).

I suggest you that when you have a doubt about vendor prefixes you should check if it is needed. For instance never existed the `-o-calc(100% - 100px)` for Opera. Or maybe you just don't need the vendor prefix because you no longer support an old version of a particular browser. For instance  you probably not need to support FF 15, if that is the case you should not use `width: -moz-calc(100% - 100px)`.

Comment: This is not an answer. Better to comment before someone gives you a downvote.

Comment: Sorry Herm it wasn't clear enough. I've just updated my answer.